# Specify WCF client source port

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp, port

I have a WCF service published on a certain address, and I want to communicate with it via a proxy generated in Visual Studio.

I want the messages from my proxy to be sent with a specific TCP source port, but it apparently assigns a random port on each call.

The problem is this: I have two hosts A and B which are running a WCF Service (the same on each host), host A has the service up on address AdA and port PA, host B on address AdB and port PB. Host A sends a message to host B. Host B performs some internal operations after the message, and then sends a message to host A. The problem is that when Host A invokes a webmethod on B, it sends a TCP message with a random src port, and one that does *not* match the port on which A has the service hosted, so the webmethod is not invoked on A because the source port assigned by WCF does not match the port the service is published at.

I've been using BasicHttpBinding so far.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it will be better to let community know WHY do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

The netPeerTcpBinding allows you to specify the outbound port number.

Comment: This binding is obsolete in .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that when Host A invokes a webmethod on B, it sends a
>   TCP message with a random src port, and one that does not match the
>   port on which A has the service hosted, so the webmethod is not
>   invoked on A because the source port assigned by WCF does not match
>   the port the service is published at.

There is no reason why A's web method should be invoked just because it receives a reply from another web service. You must explicitly call to the service. If you want A to be called in a response to A calling B, then the code in service B must make that call. Although if you have two methods that call each other like that it would just be back and forth so you would need an exit condition. Perhaps if you gave more details about what you are trying to accomplish I could offer more advice.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is possible to assign the source port for any kind of network communication, as it has to be unique.

> The source port is a next-available number assigned by TCP/IP to the
>   client. This assigned number is how the network address translation
>   method determines which user to send back the responses to (see NAT).
>   Although that same client number may be used simultaneously within
>   thousands of organizations, each TCP/IP network keeps track of its own
>   assigned numbers for use within that network only. The combination of
>   port number and IP address is called a "socket."

Read more: http://www.answers.com/topic/port-number#ixzz1jLxPzCVe

Comment: This is incorrect, NAT is used to map private addresses and ports to NAT-mapped public addresses and ports. Also, your definition of socket is also not correct; especially since there are basically two types of sockets, UDP and TCP; UDP sockets are identified by source IP address and port number, TCP are identified by source IP, source port, target IP, target port. Port numbers don't have to be unique, they are recycled actually and used for transport layer demultiplexing.

Comment: TcpClient class has a constructor that takes a local endpoint (ip and port).